# Swing - GridBagLayout button adding mistake

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout, gridbaglayout, jtabbedpane

I use this function to create tabs. When I want to add button "?" that will open the Wizard, this button appears at the right side of this JTable. How to edit this?

comp1 - "1. Dp/Drho", comp2 - "2. Df2/Drho", comp3 - "3. SDSS", comp4 - "4. Help". name1-4 - names of this tabs.[image]

```
static protected JPanel allocateUniPane(Component comp1,Component comp2,Component comp3, Component comp4,
                                        String name1, String name2, String name3, String name4){
    JPanel resultPane = new JPanel();
    GridBagLayout gridbagforUnionPane = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints cUnionPane = new GridBagConstraints();
    resultPane.setLayout(gridbagforUnionPane);

    cUnionPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    cUnionPane.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    JButton showWizard = new JButton("?");
    cUnionPane.weightx = 0.5;
    cUnionPane.weighty = 0.5;
    JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    jtp.addTab(name1, comp1);
    jtp.addTab(name2, comp2);
    jtp.addTab(name3, comp3);
    jtp.addTab(name4, comp4);
    cUnionPane.gridx = 0;
    cUnionPane.gridy = 0;
    resultPane.add(jtp,cUnionPane);
    cUnionPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    cUnionPane.weightx = 0.5;
    cUnionPane.gridx = 1;
    cUnionPane.gridy = 0;
    resultPane.add(showWizard,cUnionPane);

    return resultPane;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the button to appear to be part of the tabbed pane. You can't use a GridBagLayout (or most other layouts) because they layout positions components in two dimensions on the panel.

Maybe the OverlayLayout will do what you want since it positions components in the third dimension. For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;

public class TabbedPaneWithComponent
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout( new OverlayLayout(panel) );

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.add("1", new JTextField("one"));
        tabbedPane.add("2", new JTextField("two"));
        tabbedPane.setAlignmentX(1.0f);
        tabbedPane.setAlignmentY(0.0f);

        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Check Me");
        checkBox.setOpaque( false );
        checkBox.setAlignmentX(1.0f);
        checkBox.setAlignmentY(0.0f);

        panel.add( checkBox );
        panel.add(tabbedPane);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabbedPane With Component");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setSize(400, 100);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I found documentation about [Overlay Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html). But I don't understand how it works. What if we want the `checkBox` on the middle. I mean how do you handle the position of the items? I know it paints one object over the other. I'm not sure if I explained myself.

Comment: @Frakcool `What if we want the checkBox on the middle.` Agreed the documentation is not very good and the layout is not that intuitive. Basically you need to play with the `setAlignmentX()` property. I think you need to change the alignment of both components to be 0.5f. I can only get it to work by trial and error.

Comment: that what I need, thanks! JCheckBox looks nice, but JButton looks not so nice here because it is too big for tabs and closes bottom border.

Comment: @Denis, you can change the margins of the button to get rid of most of the space around the text by using the `setMargins(...)` method.

Comment: @camickr ok thanks. It's not my question but it seems interesting. I'm a Swing passionate and like reading these questions. That's why I asked. Thanks for the answer.